# WSO2 Stream Processor (SP) Json string cannot be parsed to a json object

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

Here I have a siddhi application setup like below:

[WSO2 SP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZdlC.png)

I have saved it and started it. I am trying to start an event in the cmd as shown below:

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hDHl.png)

But I get this error;

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee9NW.png)

Any idea as to how it may be fixed?

my understanding of this subject is rather limited and I am unsure as to what is wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please do not add images of Code, Errors, Configs, etc. make sure you add them as text to the question with proper formatting. Take a look at this post as well https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for HTTP events with a log Sink with a JSON payload.

```
@Source(type = 'http',
        receiver.url='http://localhost:8006/productionStream',
        basic.auth.enabled='false',
        @map(type='json'))
define stream SweetProductionStream (name string, amount double);

@sink(type='log')
define stream OutputStream (name string, amount double);

@info(name='passThrough')
from SweetProductionStream
select *
insert into OutputStream;
```

curl

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"event\":{\"name\":\"Cake\",\"amount\":20.12}}" http://localhost:8006/productionStream --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```